# std::unique and vector::resize

Tags: c++, vector

How does the unique and resize maintain that no repetition occurs:

```
for(map <string, vector<int> >::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    {
      vector<int>::iterator sz = unique((it->second).begin(),(it->second).end());
        (it->second).resize(distance((it->second).begin(),sz));
    }
```

The vector is sorted.

Comment: woops, overlooked that second is a vector.  The thing is that unique works only on sorted vectors. Unique pulls the non unique elements to the back of the vector and then that resize just cuts them off. Also, erase would be more viable than resize.

Comment: Actually the vector is sorted as it is input that manner.

Comment: @nRT -- What exactly is the issue?  Your question is lacking specifics.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the question is about reading documentation.

---

[`std::unique()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) pulls elements to the back of the vector, and returns an iterator to the first non unique element.

In the beginning sequence may look like: 1 1 2 2 2 3 6 6

After the call to unique the sequence changes to: 1 2 3 6 ...(duplicated).

---

Then `distance()` calculates how many unique elements are, which is distance from first unique element to first non unique element. `.resize()` just cuts off non unique part.

`.erase(sz, (it->second).end);` would be better to use in this case. Also the loop itself is rather weird.